# Navbar and Container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar in a container-class-div because i want in desktop-view the nav not touching the edge of monitor, but in mobile-view it should stretch to the sides.

I have tried two containers, one as container and the other as container-fluid and making them disappear with the hidden-xx classes, but this isn't working.

Anyone an Idea how can I solve that problem?

Comment: What about an example of your code so we can get a feeling about what you've already done so far.

Comment: just use media queries to remove the `padding-left` and `padding-right` from that specific container, when you are on mobile

Answer (score 0):

You could use `container`, its `margin` changes according to screen size, as it is set to `auto`.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't understand that really. I have the navbar in a "container" and so i have free space left and right in desktop-width, but in smartphone-width too. In the smartphone-viewport i want the bahaviour of "container-fluid", no free-space left and right from navbar. How can I realize this different styles?

Comment: yes, i understand your requirement, you should use `container`, updated my answer, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Write a media query.

For screens > 920px

```
.container{
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

For screens <= 920px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    .container {
        padding:0;
    }
}
```